# Accessing a variable in an object contained within another object when the child object is null

Tags: c#

I have the following two classes. Addresses contains a list of Address. Method GetMailingAddress will scan through AddressList looking for a particular type of address.

```
Class Addresses
{
   public List<Address> AddressList {get; set;}

   public Address MailingAddress {get { return GetMailingAddress();}
}

Class Address
{
   public Int? ID {get; set;}
}
```

To access the ID of the MailingAddress I would type the following:

```
Addresses obj = new Addresses();
int? I = obj.MailingAddress.ID
```

The problem is MailingAddress can return null. If this happens the call fails as it references ID through a null object. In this instance I would like to return null.

To work around this I use this code:

```
if(obj.MailingAddress == null)
{
    I? = null;
}
else
{
    I? = obj.MailingAddress.ID;
}
```

Is there a way to call obj.MailingAddress.ID and return null if MailingAddress is null without having to do the above If statement.

I could also create an additional method/property within class Addresses like this but again I see this as a work around, not a clean solution:

```
public int? MailingAddressID
{
    if(GetMailingAddress == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return GetMailingAddress.ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll love C# 6 then... you can do `var i = obj?.MailingAddress?.ID;` and you will get the value you want. see: https://dotnetfiddle.net/THfoBi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `int` is struct and you must use `?` or `Nullable<int>` for  making it nullable and then:

```
int? myInt = obj.MailingAddress == null ? (int?)null : (int?)obj.MailingAddress.Id;
```

But, in C# 6 you can use `?` operator which is sometimes called **[Safe Navigation Operator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator.aspx)** :

```
int? myInt = obj?.MailingAddress?.Id;
```

As an additional note, you can use [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). You can learn it from [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/patterns/article.php/c16503/Null-Object-Pattern-in-C.htm) and use this pattern also. The use of `Null Object` pattern simplifies the code and makes it less error prone.

Comment: Yes. That was an over sight on my behalf.

Comment: Great answer. I was trying to do this but just couldn't get it to work. Cannot wait until C# 6. obj?.obj?.id is very nice.

Comment: @SimonDarlow Glad it has helped. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a silly implementation of C# 6 Null Propagation syntax in C# 5:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo { Bar = new Bar { Baz = "Hello" } };
        var foo1 = new Foo();

        var i = foo._(_=>_.Bar)._(_=>_.Baz);            //equivalent to foo?.Bar?.Baz in C# 6       
        Console.WriteLine("i is '{0}'", i);             //should be 'Hello'

        var j = foo1._(_=>_.Bar)._(_=>_.Baz);           //equivalent to foo1?.Bar?.Baz in C# 6      
        Console.WriteLine("j is '{0}'",j);              //should be '' since j is null, but shouldn't throw exception either.

        Console.WriteLine("js is null? {0}", j == null);

    }
}

public class Foo 
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}

public static class ObjectExtension
{
    //Probably not a good idea to name your method _, but it's the shortest one I can find, I wish it could be _?, but can't :(
    public static K _<T, K>(this T o, Func<T, K> f) 
    {
        try 
        {
            var z = f(o);
            return z;           
        }
        catch(NullReferenceException nex) 
        {
            Trace.TraceError(nex.ToString());
            return default(K);
        }

    }
}
```

Basically I want to do `foo?.Bar?.Baz`, but since the syntax is not supported, extension method, `Func<..>` and generic to the rescue...

This way you don't need to change your object to nullable version, but you need to specify their type in the call to extension method `_`.  `foo._(_=>_.Bar)._(_=>_.Baz)` looks a bit weird, but quite terse :)

Live sample at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9R8bku

Comment: Too crazy for me. My C# knowledge cannot cope :)